# What's the theory of action listener in java?

Tags: java

I mean how could it implement the real time action, by multi threads or what?

Look, if I add an `action listener` to a `JButton`, and put the following codes in the main function,

```
while(true){
   System.out.print("a");
}
```

And I will print `b` 100 times in the action listener of JButton. After clicking the button, I expected to see 100 constant b printed, and after that there will be a string of a. However the result turns out what I expected was wrong.

So I want to ask, what the exact relationship between the action listener and the main function?
Is it like two threads or something?

I am looking forward to your answer, thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect it to print 100 when you made an infinite loop?

Comment: Good luck http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: By default, everything runs in the same thread.

Comment: @Smutje by default, Swing/AWT runs on the event thread, which is different from the main thread

Comment: @Smutje no, not everything. The code in main() runs in the main thread. The code in event listeners runs in the event dispatch thread.

Comment: Ah, UI, I overread "JButton" above.

Answer (score 1):

Basically action listener and main function are not related directly, its just that you create a JButton  and add an action listener, to perform whatever function you want it to perform. Main fuction is not involved in that unless you do so. Everytime you create the button a thread is created and runs independently.